# TypeInitializationException when opening SQLconnection with Impersonation

Tags: c#, exception, impersonation, sqlconnection

I have a problem with TypeInitializationException in windows forms app, when opening SQLconnection while using impersonation (when impersonation removed everything works) and I can't figure out how to solve the problem.

Here is the StackTrace:

```
   v System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
   v System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Initialize(IDataServices dataServices, Object connection)
   v System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping)
   v System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection)
   v CallBackCvop.Persistance.UnitOfWork..ctor(String connectionString)
   v CallBackCvop.MainForm.RefreshOrders()
   v CallBackCvop.MainForm.BTN_Search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   v System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   v System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   v System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   v System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   v CallBackCvop.Program.Main()
```

Here is the StackTrace for innerException

```
   v System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   v System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.SetNamesAndVersion(String applicationFilename, Assembly exeAssembly, Boolean isHttp)
   v System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   v System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   v System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   v System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   v System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   v System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   v System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
```

Here is my impersonation code:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public class Impersonation : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly SafeTokenHandle _handle;
        private readonly WindowsImpersonationContext _context;

        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

        public Impersonation(string domain, string username, string password)
        {
            var ok = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
                           LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 0, out this._handle);
            if (!ok)
            {
                var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser returned error code {0}.", errorCode));
            }

            this._context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._context.Dispose();
            this._handle.Dispose();
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

        public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
        {
            private SafeTokenHandle()
                : base(true) { }

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

            protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
            {
                return CloseHandle(handle);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is - I have used this impersonation code before in different ap and everything worked. I'm quite desperate, any help? Thanks.

Here's the connection string:

```
private readonly string _connectionString = "data source = xxx\\xxx; initial catalog = xxx; integrated security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Here's the opening:

```
    using (UnitOfWork frt = new UnitOfWork(_connectionString))
    {
        _outCalls.DownloadOutCalls(frt, _orders.ReturnSetOfNumbers());
    }
```

**UnitOfWork (here you get the TypeInitializationException):**

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        ....repositories...

        private readonly DataContext _context;


        public UnitOfWork(string connectionString)
        {
            _context = new DataContext(connectionString);


            ....repositories...
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_context != null)
                    _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

**The innerexception is FileNotFoundException, but it seems to reference .exe itself - i do not understand this.**

Edit - 8.10.2018
I Found out that everything works fine when .exe is on my Desktop but not on shared intranet drive. But the impersonated account has the same rights as my account. 
And as stated before, I have a different app using the same impersonation code, same connection string and everything works on both my desktop & shared drive.

Edit - 8.10.2018 - 11:00
So its crashed by....
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(pathToExe),

- I checked the rights of the impersonated account - everything OK,
- I tried the app without impersonation and my account - everything OK,
- I tried the app with impersonating my account(should work) - not working

Comment: No help? :( ...

Answer (score 0):

So...
After some time a figured a workaround. 
It seems that an error was in --- System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(pathToExe) so moved my impersonation call from program to unit of work. Changing it this way:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    public IOrderRepository Orders { get; }
    public ICallRepository OutCalls { get; }
    public ILoginRepository Login { get; }

    private readonly DataContext _context;


    public UnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        _context = new DataContext(new SqlConnection());

        using (new Impersonation("domain", "user", "password"))
            _context.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        Orders = new OrderRepository(_context);
        OutCalls = new CallRepository(_context);
        Login = new LoginRepository(_context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context != null)
                _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```